# Docker-compose commands in yml not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and am trying to get a few containers up and running using a docker-compose.yml file. But when i run the following command inside the cocker toolbox cli

```
docker-compose.yml up
```

I get the following errors:

[image: Docker-Compose Errors]

As you can see, if I run the command

```
docker-compose -v
```

I get the version and build info which means it has been installed.

I have googled a lot but failed to find any solution. Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run the .yml file. Compose doesn't work like that.

Just run: `docker-compose` in the directory where docker-compose.yml resides. Docker-compose will automatically find the file.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked, Thanks! Will accept it as an answer as it is more precise with the specification of the directory where the command should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to run a yml file (which at best, bash interprets as a script). You need to run `docker-compose`, not `docker-compose.yml`. The latter is the input config file to the former.

```
docker-compose config
```